# Variance in the direction of a unit vector — intuition behind formula?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say we have a set of data and we want to calculate the variance in the direction of a particular unit vector $ u $. The formula for the variance in the direction of $ u $ is $ \sigma_u = u \cdot \Sigma u $ where $ \Sigma $ is the covariance matrix.

I can easily prove that this is correct algebraically, but I feel like I’m missing some deeper intuition. What does it mean to first transform the vector $ u $ by the covariance matrix? And then what does it mean to dot that result against the original vector $ u $?

In the 2-dimensional case, we can expand the first transformation as follows:

$ \Sigma u = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{xx} & \sigma_{xy} \\\\ \sigma_{yx} & \sigma_{yy} \\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u_x \\\\ u_y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} u_x \sigma_{xx} + u_y \sigma_{xy} \\\\ u_x \sigma_{yx} + u_y \sigma_{yy} \\\\ \end{pmatrix} $

And at this point I already feel like I’m missing something. If we focus on just the x-component of the transformed vector $ u_x \sigma_{xx} + u_y \sigma_{xy} $, it feels like I should have some sort of intuition for what’s happening. Colloquially, covariance is always described as “how much $ x $ varies with $ y $” so this expansion feels like we’re calculating something profound and fundamental. Like $ u_y \sigma_{xy} $ feels like it’s “the amount of variance in $ x $ coming from the y-component of $ u $ — or something like that.

Could someone help me crystallize the intuition around this formula?

Answer (score 1):

The intuition around this is that the dot product is often used to find the [projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) of a quantity in the direction of a unit vector. Or in other words, it measures "how much" of the quantity exists in the direction of that unit vector.

Or to look at it yet another way, if you apply a [change of basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) from the default Cartesian coordinates to a different set of coordinates that includes $u$ as one of the basis vectors, then the dot product with $u$ captures the coefficient of $u$ in this new basis.